# Pandas(Python) : Fill empty cells with with previous row value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to fill empty cells with with previous row value if they start with number. For example, I have

```
    Text    Text    
    30      Text    Text    
            Text    Text    
            Text    Text    
    31      Text    Text
    Text    Text    
    31      Text    Text    
            Text    Text    
            Text    Text    
    32      Text    Text
    Text    Text    
            Text    Text    
            Text    Text    
            Text    Text    
            Text    Text
```

I however, want to have

```
Text    Text    
30      Text    Text    
30      Text    Text    
30      Text    Text    
31      Text    Text
Text    Text    
31      Text    Text    
31      Text    Text    
31      Text    Text    
32      Text    Text
Text    Text    
        Text    Text    
        Text    Text    
        Text    Text    
        Text    Text
```

I tried to reach this by using this code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('DATA.csv',sep='\t', dtype=object, error_bad_lines=False)
data = data.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
print(data)
```

but it did not work.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: What are the values of the "empty" cells? `fillna` only fills cells whose value is `NaN`. To use `fillna`, first replace "" with `numpy.nan`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed "empty" values to NaN with regex. But it did not work.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

First, replace your empty cells with NaNs:

```
df[df[0]==""] = np.NaN
```

Now, Use `ffill()`:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
#       0
#0  Text
#1    30
#2    30
#3    30
#4    31
#5  Text
#6    31
#7    31
#8    31
#9    32
```

Comment: Does it work with string values? Because I'm trying to fill my empty cells with previous row value that is a string, and it still returns `NaN`.

Comment: Is it correct to say df[df["column_name"]==""] = np.NaN ?

Comment: Not sure that would work as I'm on working on a similar issue. ffill would fill everything.

Comment: @joasa setting the Flag "inplace" allowed me to do the same with string values. Example: ```frame[column_name].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)```

Comment: I think it should be `np.nan` rathar than `np.NaN` in the first line.  For some reason my code treated `np.Nan` as a string and `np.nan` as true nan.

Comment: Could anyone explain what the parts of the `df[df[0]==""] = np.NaN` statement? `df` is obviously the `DataFrame` and `np.NaN` is the special value "Not a Number". But the rest seems cryptic. Is `0` the column?

Answer (score 14):

I think you can first get `NaN` instead `whitespaces`:

```
df.Text = df.Text[df.Text.str.strip() != '']

print (df)
    Text Text.1      
0     30   Text  Text
1    NaN   Text  Text
2    NaN   Text  Text
3     31   Text  Text
4   Text   Text   NaN
5     31   Text  Text
6    NaN   Text  Text
7    NaN   Text  Text
8     32   Text  Text
9   Text   Text   NaN
10   NaN   Text  Text
11   NaN   Text  Text
12   NaN   Text  Text
13   NaN   Text  Text
```

Then use [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html) (same as [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with parameter `ffill`), get [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) for [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) for replace `NaN` if not numeric forward filling `NaN`, last replace `NaN` by empty string by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
orig = df.Text.copy()
df.Text = df.Text.ffill()
mask1 = pd.to_numeric(df.Text, errors='coerce')
df.Text = df.Text.where(mask1, orig).fillna('')
print (df)
    Text Text.1      
0     30   Text  Text
1     30   Text  Text
2     30   Text  Text
3     31   Text  Text
4   Text   Text   NaN
5     31   Text  Text
6     31   Text  Text
7     31   Text  Text
8     32   Text  Text
9   Text   Text   NaN
10         Text  Text
11         Text  Text
12         Text  Text
13         Text  Text
```

Comment: thank you so much. However when I run your code I get this: 

line 2672, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Text'

I could not understand what .Text means.  (I wrote Text but actually there are some string values).

Comment: Text is column name, try use `df.col1` or `df['col 1']` instead.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you want to fill empty cells with the previous row value, you can just use a recursive function like:

```py
def same_as_upper(col:pd.Series)-> pd.Series:
    '''
    Recursively fill NaN rows with the previous value
    '''
    if any(pd.Series(col).isna()):
        col=pd.Series(np.where(col.isna(), col.shift(1), col))
        return same_as_upper(col)
    else:
        return col
```

Applying the function using `df['A']=same_as_upper(df['A'])`, this simple case with your data would render:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Text | Text | nan |
| 30 | Text | Text |
| 30 | Text | Text |
| 30 | Text | Text |
| 31 | Text | Text |
| Text | Text | nan |
| 31 | Text | Text |
| 31 | Text | Text |
| 31 | Text | Text |
| 32 | Text | Text |
| Text | Text | nan |
| Text | Text | Text |
| Text | Text | Text |
| Text | Text | Text |
| Text | Text | Text |

However, you have the additional constraint of not replicating the previous value if this value is not an integer. In that case, one solution is add a sample value in the appropriate location, use the same function and then replace the sample value for `nan`:

```py
df.loc[11,'A']=999
df['A']=same_as_upper(df['A'])
df['A']=df['A'].replace(999,np.nan)
```

Result:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Text | Text | nan |
| 30 | Text | Text |
| 30 | Text | Text |
| 30 | Text | Text |
| 31 | Text | Text |
| Text | Text | nan |
| 31 | Text | Text |
| 31 | Text | Text |
| 31 | Text | Text |
| 32 | Text | Text |
| Text | Text | nan |
| nan | Text | Text |
| nan | Text | Text |
| nan | Text | Text |
| nan | Text | Text |

Comment: For the small amount of data I'll be working on, this is perfect. And it easily gives the user the option to assign the values to a new column!