# Pandas Dataframe Assign Value Using Previous N Row Value

Tags: python, pandas

This is my pandas dataframe.

```
                     Status   
index                                    
2011-01-10 16:00:00  Active
2011-01-11 16:00:00  
2011-01-12 16:00:00  Inactive
2011-01-13 16:00:00  
2011-01-14 16:00:00     
2011-01-18 16:00:00
```

I would like to fill the blank value of the column 'Status' using previous N row value. The result look like following.

```
                     Status   
index                                    
2011-01-10 16:00:00  Active
2011-01-11 16:00:00  Active
2011-01-12 16:00:00  Inactive
2011-01-13 16:00:00  Inactive
2011-01-14 16:00:00  Inactive   
2011-01-18 16:00:00  Inactive
```

What's the best way to do?

Comment: are those empty rows? if they are, you can convert to  null values (np.nan) and downward fill using fillna

Comment: it is not empty row. the column value is blank.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas(Python) : Fill empty cells with with previous row value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212273/pandaspython-fill-empty-cells-with-with-previous-row-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the rows are already null, then [forward fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) should be sufficient:

```
  df.ffill()
```

if the rows are empty string, then [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with np.nan, and forward fill:

```
  df.replace('',np.nan).ffill()


                       status
 index  
2011-01-10 16:00:00    Active
2011-01-11 16:00:00    Active
2011-01-12 16:00:00    Inactive
2011-01-13 16:00:00    Inactive
2011-01-14 16:00:00    Inactive
2011-01-18 16:00:00    Inactive
```